# jQuery change input name before post in ajax

Tags: jquery

I have input field.

I want to change input name before post in ajax.

For example:

```
 <input name="one" id="input_id" >
 var input_data = $('#input_id').serialize();

$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  "other.php",
                        data: input_data,
                        success: function(msg){
                        }
                    });
```

I want to get in post not $_POST["one"], but $_POST["another_name"].

Sorry for bad english ...

Comment: what kind of data in your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "other.php",
    data: {
       "xxx": $('#input_id').val()
    },
    success: function(msg){
    }
});
```

replace `xxx` with any name

Comment: In the jQuery docs, they don't use double quotes for the data key, but it seems both are working, any idea about this ?

Comment: You need to use `"` if the key has special characters like -, or spaces

Answer (score 1):

You need only this input ? Just send your ajax data like this :

```
var myData = $('input_id').val();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
    url:  "other.php",
    data: {another_name : myData},
    success: function(msg){
    }
});
```